# How to write JPA native query to join two tables. Eclipseink JPA,Glassfish3.x,EJB3.1, MySQL

Tags: mysql, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, glassfish-3, nativequery

What would be the correct way writing JPA native queries with joins and with Eclipselink JPA2.0 entities?

Can some one tell me to execute the following SQL query using Eclipselink JPA native queries or JPQL?

SQL query is: 
    Select e.EmployeeName,e.EmpId, d.DeptId from Employee e, Department d join e.DeptId on d.DeptId where e.DeptId=d.DeptId

JPA Entity bean code snippet

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")

@JoinColumn(name = "DeptId", referencedColumnName = "DeptId")
@ManyToOne
    private Department DeptId;

@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e")})

    //more auto generated named queries using NetBeans
```

The JPA entity class "Employee" implements java.io.Serializable and the default constructor contains all mandatory fields.

What is the correct way to map jpa entity with My-SQL tables

Many to one relation:  Employee.DeptId --> Department.DeptId  Employee.RoleId --> JobRoles.RoleId

Employee.RoleId --> Skills.SkillId
After succeeded with two tables I want to join three tables.

I was going thru the Ecipselink user-guide but could not get it.
Would some one provide me code snippets or direct me to correct resource.

I have gone through EclipseLink JPA online guide:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA

I am using native query because Eclipse link JPA supports it and JPQL does not give complete portability.
  I wrote and developed a sample jsf-jpa application with jpa entities mapped to single table. With Netbeans IDE, it did not take much time generate and execute JPQL queries.

I want to use native queries and/or stored procedures execute JPA entities.
It would be more productive if I could use my existing skills in SQL queries and stored procedures provided the JPA implementation does not give much issues with the same.

**Update**:
Native SQL queries can be used according to Section [3.8.15 SQL Queries of JSR 317: [JavaTM Persistence API, Version 2.0][1]](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1366282276_abf8b3a9d5be1e4f66a83ae56f20eb31)
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/

> The SQL query facility is intended to provide support for those cases
>   where it is necessary to use the native SQL of the target database in
>   use (and/or where the Java Persistence query language cannot be used).
>   Native SQL queries are not expected to be portable across databases

Hence I believe it is nothing wrong to use native query, because portability is not required for me.

Comment: JB Nizet, I have updated the post. I believe it make sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28091/discussion-between-sree-rama-and-jb-nizet)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28095/discussion-between-sree-rama-and-jb-nizet)

Comment: Chris, I am doing it and update you by Monday.  I have already done simple and after that some more jpa entities in a JSF JPA crud. Let me put code snippets.

Comment: Chris, I want to use native query because JPA supports it and want to utilize both JPQLand native queries. The portability with JPQL is not required for my application. After getting better clarity how to use JPQL, I want to choose latest and stable version of one of the JPA2 impementations i) Eclipselink or ii)Hibernate JPA.

Comment: @JBNizet, I would like to utilise my developers with Java and SQL skills, without much learning JPQL. It make sense for me.

Comment: @JBNizet, pls undo the down-vote?

Comment: Chris, I turned to EclipseLink logging to Fine, Finest. The native query insert the records in My-SQL tables properly. May be I need to correct my jpa entitiy and JSF xhtml view.

Comment: @JBNizet,    undo the down vote, or do you have further feedback on my question?

Comment: @Chris, undo the down vote. I can improve the question if you have any feedback please.

Comment: @JBNizet, I would appreciate if you would undo the down vote or give me your feedback on the updated question.  Because your comments were valid before I updated the question, but no now.

Comment: @Chris, undo the down vote pls.

Comment: @JBNizet/@Chris  Gentle reminder. Undo the down vote.

Comment: @JBNizet, pls undo the down-vote.

Comment: @Chris, pls undo the down-vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native query executed successfully, The Section 3.8.15  of JSR 317 specification is helpful to understand the syntax, besides hit and trials with my code.